# Free struct array with char **

Tags: c, free

I have the following struct:

Can I simply call free(pArr)? Do I need to also free the gradeArr I malloc? How can I do so?

```
 struct person {
     char * name;
     int age;
     char ** gradeArr;

 }

  // array of structs
  struct person * pArr;

  void function(){
      pArr = malloc(5 * sizeof(*pArr));
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          pArr[i].gradeArr = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
          int j;
          for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
              pArr[i].gradeArr[j] = "B";

          }

      }

  }
```

Comment: pArr[i].gradeArr = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*)); allocates memory for pointer. allocate memory for char data. then yes you need to free all memory allocated using malloc

Answer (score 1):

Anything you `malloc` you must `free`.

Whatever you assigned the result of calling `malloc` to, pass that in a call to `free` to free it.

Comment: Simple as that, indeed. Which of course means, if you `malloc()` in a loop, you'll have to `free()` in a loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firs you should free all `pArr[i].gradeArr` and only after that free `pArr`.

Different order of `free` may cause some problems (you may loose pointers to allocated `pArr[i].gradeArr`-s ).

Comment: "*Different order of free may cause some problems*" <- I know what you mean here, but in general, this is wrong, order doesn't matter. You just shouldn't `free()` memory containing other pointers you have to `free()` first, as long as you didn't save them anywhere else.

Comment: @FelixPalmen sorry I don't get it. Can you explain it once more?

Comment: Just wanted to make clear that the standard library doesn't care in which order you call `free()`. Your wording might be interpreted this way.